# How can I call a Gtk API from another thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk, polling

I've written a `C` program in which I implemented some `threads` to make `polling`. When something happens in the thread I have to modify some `Widgets` created in `main` function.
This program sometimes crashes when a `thread` tries to do an operation on a `Widget`, for example simply calling the function `gtk_widget_hide`, and I discovered that's because I must not call any `GTK` API from another thread.

How can I do what I've described before avoiding any crashes? Is it possible, considering I need threads?

That's an example of what my code does

```
static GtkWidget* widget;

void check_user_action(){
    while(!user_does_action){
        g_sleep(1);
    }

    gtk_widget_hide(main_widget);
}

void main(){
    widget = //I skip widget creation
    gtk_widget_show_all(widget);

    g_thread_new("check_user_action", check_user_action, NULL);

    //do something else
}
```

That's only an example, but assume the only way I have to `check_user_action` is with `polling`.

Comment: I am not sure if it is sufficient for your needs, but you could pass the task to call any GTK API to your main thread via `g_idle_add()`

Comment: I added an example of my code. Can you explain me the usage of `g_idle_add()` and if it works for my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your snippet you can pass the task to your main thread:

```
gboolean my_hide_func(gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_widget *widget = (gtk_widget*) user_data;
    gtk_widget_hide(widget);
    return FALSE;
}

void check_user_action(){
    while(!user_does_action){
        g_sleep(1);
    }
    g_idle_add(my_hide_func, main_widget);
}
```

This will enqueue a request to call that function in the queue for the main thread running your GTK application.